# Is WSO2 IS PEP centralized and how can i integrate it into WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I would like to use/customize the PEP implementation provided by WSO2 IS, but I am not sure about two things:

1. if the PEP would be centralized or not. In other words, does each Web service has its own PEP or is it the same? In practice where would the PEP be placed?

Also, Does is there any examples of how a PEP implementation can be integrated or incorporated into an WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus? In other words, how can we use the two together?

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about WSO2ESB, There is entitlement mediator which is the PEP for WSO2 Identity Server. There must be one PEP implementation.  But it can be used by several web services. In ESB,  mediator is something that you can engage with the message path to intercept the message. Entitlement mediator can be used as same. It can be engaged with multiple proxy services in the ESB.

You can even write new PEP as a ESB mediator and engage your custom mediator in to the message path.  You can refer [this](http://soasecurity.org/2013/11/28/how-to-wso2esb-how-to-write-custom-mediator/) document on writing a new custom mediator. Also, you can reuse the PEP client code that can be found [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/2012/06/14/pep-client-for-wso2is-pdp/). Basically you want to modify the PEP client code as a ESB custom mediator